# What is the definition of differentiation in normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

I'm trying to generalize implicit&inverse function theorems in Euclidean spaces to the context of Banach spaces.

I'm wondering what would be the definition of differentiation in Banach space and below is what I guessed:

> Let $V,W$ be **nonzero** norned spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ and $E$ be an open subset of $V$ and $p\in E$. (Under this setting, $p$ is a limit point of $E$)
>
> Let $f:E\rightarrow W$ be a function.
>
> Then, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff there exists a linear transformation $A:V\rightarrow W$ such that $\lim_{x\to p} \frac{||f(x)-f(p)-A(x-p)||}{||x-p||} = 0$.

Is this the correct definition?

Or, should I require $A$ to be bounded?

Comment: One reference I liked that dealt with such things was Kantorovich & Akilov's "Functional analysis".

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. I just borrowed it.

Comment: Your mileage may vary, but I was very fond of the prove of the implicit funtion theorem in Lang's Real Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard definition requires $A$ to be bounded. There are many text on nonlinear analysis, [like this one](http://books.google.es/books/about/A_Primer_of_Nonlinear_Analysis.html?id=dVSTUben3QoC&redir_esc=y).